# How do I build the AWS Amplify sample project on GitHub on my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I assume that there is an AWS Amplify sample project available on GitHub.
That sample has a number of backends already configured, including Auth and API.

How can I build that source code on my AWS account?
I have full access to my AWS account.
I have built a completely new application on Amplify.
How do I build an Amplify project created by a complete stranger on my AWS account?

Of course, I will allow the S3 bucket name and Cognito user pool ID to be different values when building on my AWS account, as they are globally unique values.
I will not tolerate a way to delete the amplify folder and manually redo all the amplify add auth, etc.